error connecting to socket.io with python
I need to scrape the latest informations from the website: https://x13.bet/double
And I saw that all the informations from the website that I need is from: https://s.x13.bet:2053/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P4gHupt&sid=G6b53IG6BpYCrmFsAFdB
I would like to know how can I scrape these informations from the socket with python,
Note that if you enter on the website I mentioned you will get:
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Bad request"
}

But there are real informations in there. I saw on the preview tab:

I already tested with:
import socketio

url = "https://s.x13.bet:2053"

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected.")

@sio.event
def message(data):
    print("Message received:", data)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected.")

sio.connect(url, transports=['polling'])

sio.wait()

It just returns to me that it's connected, but nothing of the real data...
Can someone please help me? I'm trying this for about 5 days :c

There doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with your code. It's just that the server isn't sending you anything. Do this: sio = socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True) then you'll be able to see what's going on

Then how can I access the data on the website from a webhook?
